# ¿Como puedo cambiar el icono de un Windows Form?

Tags: c#

La ventana está abierta con 2 diferentes botones y muestra diferentes controles, dependiendo del botón con que fue abierta, pero no se como cambiar el icono dependiendo el botón con que fue instanciada.

La propiedad `Icon` funciona perfecto pero solo cuando el icono es único para el Form; agregue un icono en la ubicación `Properties.Resources` pero no funciona, no lanza ninguna excepción y tampoco me funciona si utilizo una ruta relativa donde se encuentra el icono `.ico` que quiero utilizar.

Answer (score 2):

En cada boton tendrias que agregarle la siguiente linea:

```
this.Icon = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.Hopstarter_Rounded_Square_Microsoft_Excel;
This.Icon = tuAplicacion.Propiedades.Recursos.ElNombreDelIcono;
```

Asegúrate de haber insertado primero el icono en los recursos del programa accediendo a `proyecto/propiedades (ultima opcion)/` y da clic en la sección de recursos. Añadir las imágenes es muy fácil, solo tienes que arrastrar los iconos de tu computadora hacia la ventana de recursos.

Comment: Gracias así lo hice pero al escribir el punto despues de `Resources.` estan disponibles los iconos que agregue pero sigue sin mostrarlo en la ventana del Form.

Comment: `private void boton_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Project.Carpeta.Subcarpeta.MyForm aa = new Carpeta.Subcarpeta.MyForm();

            aa.Icon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon;

        }`                                                                                                                  Al parecer estaban pendientes de agregar pero listo ya funciono en cada botón creé una instancia del mismo Form y a dicho objeto le pase    `Properties.Resources.MyIcon;` y funciono ... gracias @TwoDent y @Mitsu Gami

Comment: @AlecRaya Si esta respuesta te ayudó a solucionar el problema, considera **[aceptarla](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/127)** haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda.